# Bluetooth device getting disconnect automatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am connecting blue-tooth device to my android App. On onItemCLick i am getting the device and calling createBond(). It is getting connect but immediately it is getting disconnect. Below is the code what i am using for connectivity-

```
private boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)throws Exception { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  

}
```

---

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        String bDevice = (String) mLvDevices.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String str = bDevice.substring(bDevice.length() - 17);
        BluetoothDevice device = null;

        for(int i=0; i<= mBTDeviceList.size()-1; i++) {
            if(mBTDeviceList.get(i).getAddress().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
                device = mBTDeviceList.get(i);
            }
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), device.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        BaseActivity baseActivity = (BaseActivity) getActivity();
        baseActivity.setBtDevice(device);

        if(device != null) {
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(device);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```